# Ember FontAwesome not displaying some of free svg icons

Tags: javascript, css, svg, ember.js, font-awesome

I am working a rewrite of of an application that was previously built with Ember 3.12 and now being tested with 4.20.  I am building out a few components and decided to mess around with the `footer` and it requires a simple `span` that had some text and a github icon.  Previously we used `"ember-font-awesome": "^3.1",` but I think no-one is currently maintaining the addon and we are looking to use `"@fortawesome/ember-fontawesome": "^0.3.2",` with:

```
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
```

After setting things up there are a few icons that work but some that don't for instance: `<FaIcon @icon="github" @prefix="fa"/>`.  I put the prefix attribute in because it stated that you may need to do this because of the default `fas` prefix and `github` icon uses `fa`. Here is the error message I get in the browser console.

`fa-icon.js:117 Could not find icon: iconName=github, prefix=fa. You may need to add it to your icons.js.`

So I added an `icon.js` file to the `config/` folder I am still having no luck displaying specific icons.  Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix should be `fab` not `fa`, for it is in the **b**rands package.

Comment: Thank you for that @andrey.  The docs on the repo talk about prefixes but they fail to mention when you are faced with pro icons and brands.

Comment: I was very surprised to realise that, so no wonder you've stumbled upon this